# how can i express this symbol in latex (it looks similar Sigma)

Tags: latex, pdflatex

[see this image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LJwZ.png)

[see this image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERtkw.png)

in mathsymbol, what is it in latex? it means covariance matrices.

i draw this symbol in Detexify, but i can't find it.

i ask Chat GPT, but it always say \Sigma,

and mathpix said 4 or \Phi ...

i want to know this symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the symbol has a specific name, it is definitely a Sigma, just barred.
If you want to draw this in LaTeX, you can use the math versions of the `\Xlap` commands (where `X` is one of `l` `c` `r`) offered by the `mathtools` package, that allow printing a symbol without it taking any actual horizontal space, effectively enabling you to superpose symbols.

Here I use the `\mathrlap` command to print a sizeless Sigma, then again for printing a vertical bar preceded by a space of 2 points (change it to your taste), and finally a `\phantom` command that does the opposite: print a space the size of a Sigma, but invisible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\( A \mathrlap{\Sigma} \mathrlap{\hspace{2pt}\vert} \phantom{\Sigma} Z \)

\end{document}
```

[A render of the equation given above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDNx1.png)